# Strange Looping Issue with LWC JS

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I am running into a strange looping/re-rendering issue with my client-side JS.

`data` is an array of objects containing emailTemplate data. There are 3 objects in this case. Each has a field of `Name, subject, body` and `Id`.

[image]

**JS**

```
  //decorate objects
  @api emailTemplates = [];
  @api selectedTemplates = [];
  @track selectedEmails = [];
  @track showEmailData = false;

  //bring in emails from apex
  @wire(getEmails) getEmailTemplates({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.emailTemplates = data;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    console.log(error);
  }

  //set getter for html to get all emails
  get emailOptions() {
    let returnedEmailOptions = [];
    if (this.emailTemplates) {
      console.log(this.emailTemplates);
      this.emailTemplates.forEach(email => {
        returnedEmailOptions.push({ label: email.Name, value: email.Id });
      });
    }
    return returnedEmailOptions;
  }
  //handle picklist name change and show change
  handleEmailNameChange(event) {
    this.selectedEmails = event.target.value;
    console.log(this.selectedEmails);
    this.emailTemplates.forEach(email => {
      console.log(email.Id);
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
      <template if:true={emailOptions}>
          <lightning-checkbox-group
            name="emailTemplateNameSelect"
            label="Select the Email Template Name"
            value={selectedEmails}
            options={emailOptions}
            onchange={handleEmailNameChange}
            class="slds-p-around_small"
          >
       </lightning-checkbox-group>
      </template>
```

`SelectedEmails` will never update correctly. It will always hold the values of all three objects in the array regardless of selection

[image]

Instead of all three objects, just the one selected object should show.

[image]

Comment: can you try this instead?
`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedEmails));`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal the console.log will show the string value but all three values still show in addition.

Comment: Ain't you printing those array values in for Each

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This code does nothing like what you describe/think it should be doing.

Comment: @sfdcfox I am trying to show the HtmlValue field for each value ```emailOption``` Id that is selected. My initial thought was to use the filter method i.e ```this.selectedTemplate = this.emailTemplates.filter(email => email.Id === this.selectedEmails)``` but I am running into some trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Ee6MZ9QSU/1/edit) that should demonstrate what I think you're trying to accomplish.

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  @api emailTemplates = [
    {
      Id: "Id1",
      Name: "Demo 1",
      Subject: "Demo 1",
    },
    {
      Id: "Id2",
      Name: "Demo 2",
      Subject: "Demo 2",
    },
    {
      Id: "Id3",
      Name: "Demo 3",
      Subject: "Demo 3",
    },
  ];
  @track selectedEmails = [];

  //set getter for html to get all emails
  get emailOptions() {
    return (this.emailTemplates || []).map((email) => ({
      label: email.Name,
      value: email.Id,
    }));
  }
  //handle picklist name change and show change
  handleEmailNameChange(event) {
    this.selectedEmails = event.target.value;
  }
  get selectedTemplates() {
    return this.emailTemplates.filter((email) =>
      this.selectedEmails.includes(email.Id)
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-checkbox-group
      if:true={emailOptions}
      name="emailTemplateNameSelect"
      label="Select the Email Template Name"
      value={selectedEmails}
      options={emailOptions}
      onchange={handleEmailNameChange}
      class="slds-p-around_small"
    >
    </lightning-checkbox-group>
  <div for:each={selectedTemplates} for:item="template" key={template.Id}>
      {template.Subject}
  </div>    
</template>
```

Comment: You saved me 3 hours of debugging. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.